# Referencing a particular location in google maps

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps

I am trying to include google maps on a homepage for the first time and just found the code which creates a google map with a particular location -

```
var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(53.65914, 0.072050)
```

and I don't know how to change the location where the marker is- where can I find the location coordinates? Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
 <title> Map </title>
 <style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">   

</script>
  <script>
    var map;
    function initialize()
    {
        var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(53.65914, 0.072050);

        var mapOptions = 
        {
            zoom: 10,
            center: myLatlng1,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);


        <?php
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY ID DESC");
            while($row =mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                $desc = $row['DESCRIPTION'];
                $location = $row['LOCATION'];
                $counter += 1; 
            ?>

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $location; ?>),
            map: map,
            title: '<?php echo $desc; ?>',
            icon: '/image/cam.png'
        });

       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);  
    }

    var showPosition = function (position) 
       {
           map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,  
position.coords.longitude), 16);

       }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: google maps has [lots of examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/#basics) to help you figure out how to use their `API`

Comment: To change the location of the marker give it new co-ordinates or create a new marker. This is the piece of code that sets the marker location - `position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $location; ?>)`

Comment: That doesn't create a new location but i just saw, the only thing i have to do is to go on http://www.gps-coordinates.net type in the address I want the marker to point at and exchange the coordinates. thats it.

Comment: No that doesnt create a new location but the function its part of does. Creating a new marker and adding new co-ordinates will create a new location. Changing the position of the marker will change its position. In the code above the location is coming from the `sql` query within the `php`.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy . First go to google maps and select the location you want to zoom in on. Once there look at the url at the top of the page it should look like this:

```
  https://www.google.com/maps/@44.0005355,-71.0799974,12z
```

This is your lat long 44.0005355 and -71.0799974 Just replace them with the ones you have.

Answer (score 0):

The portion of code that set the marker ( included the  position)  is this

```
     var yourLat = 45.2323; // is only sample value
     ver yourLng = 14.1818; // is only sample value
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(yourLat, yourLng),
        map: map,
        title: 'your title',
        icon: '/image/cam.png'
    });
```

You must assign the coord in  google map notation so if you haven't this coord use google maps and click the point you desise. the coord appear in a box